# ¿Como Leer múltiples libros de excel que tienen más de una hoja?

Tags: r, excel, datatables

Quisiera preguntar si pueden ayudarme con esta duda... Quiero cargar varios libros de excel en R, pero esos libros tienen varias hojas

Yo hice el siguiente código

```
setwd("path")

country_list <- list.files(getwd())

countries_as_list <- lapply(country_list, read_excel)

library(data.table)

prices_table <- rbindlist(countries_as_list, idcol = "id", fill = TRUE)
```

y con eso pude consolidar en un solo data table la primera hoja de cada libro de excel, pero quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme a hacer lo mismo pero para la segunda hoja de cada libro.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

[`read_excel()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/0.1.1/topics/read_excel) tiene un parámetro `sheet` que establece que hoja del Excel deseas leer:

```
# Por ejemplo, para leer la hoja 2 de cada excel.
countries_as_list <- lapply(country_list, read_excel, sheet = 2)
```

Comment: pero no me funciona porque en los archivos de origen las hojas tienen distintos nombres... Sabes que podría hacer?

Comment: No debería ser ese el problema, fijate que estamos accediendo por un índice y no por un nombre. Revisa que solo estés leyendo planillas excel y no cualquier otro archivo que hubiera en esa carpeta: ` list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".xls")`